# how i can format a column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i want to format a column in oracl 10g 
its type is date
I want to show me always only hours and minutes 
any solution with alter ..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show only hours / minutes from a `timestamp` field, you can use:

```sql
select to_char( sysdate, 'HH-MI' ) as sysdate_format from dual;
```

[Date/Time Formatting in Oracle](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6381/index-en.html)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then you are **wrong**. `DATE` datatype in Oracle does contain time component.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is what you have now:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'ddmmyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDAT
------
131019
```

One option is to use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
13.10.2019 08:46:16

SQL>
```

but it requires you to *always* use it; another is to `alter session` and set desired format mask (which is probably what you want):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
13.10.2019 08:45:50

SQL> select min(hiredate) from emp;

MIN(HIREDATE)
-------------------
17.12.1980 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show just the time component of a `date`, you need to convert the value to a string.

For the hours in a 24-hour format, you can use:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI')
from dual;
```

Of course, `sysdate` is a built-in `date` value.  You would use whatever value or column you desire.